Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.server.RequestHandler.handleRequest
I'm trying to use Vaadin 24.4.0.beta1 with Java 17 with Intellij IDEA. I downloaded a sample project from start.vaadin.com, it's a chat view with multiple channels - Flow element.
I tried editing this code for a little bit. I don't have Vaadin tools, so I checked changes in my browser. So, when I made a change to code, I pressed run 'Application' and when I ended, just stopped 'Application'.
I don't have a clue but I constantly started to receive the next Exception, when I added // todo.
ERROR 48164 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.server.RequestHandler.handleRequest(com.vaadin.flow.server.Vaadin session, 
com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinRequest, com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinResponse)" 
because "handler" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.server.RequestHandler.handleRequest(com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession, com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinRequest, com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinResponse)" because "handler" is null
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.SessionRequestHandler.handleRequest(SessionRequestHandler.java:64) ~[flow-server-24.4.0.beta1.jar:24.4.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1577) ~[flow-server-24.4.0.beta1.jar:24.4.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:398) ~[flow-server-24.4.0.beta1.jar:24.4.0.beta1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106) ~[vaadin-spring-24.4.0.beta1.jar:na]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:653) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:142) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:178) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]

I don't know what to do with it except for creating new project and starting all over until again gaining the same exception?
It helps when I clear all generated file and folder in project and build the app with another vaadin.version. ./mvnw in terminal isn't working, I got the next Exception all the time:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:24.3.11:prepare-frontend (default) on project chat-app: Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:24.3.11:prepare-frontend failed: U
nable to load the mojo 'prepare-frontend' in the plugin 'com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:24.3.11' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com/
vaadin/flow/plugin/maven/PrepareFrontendMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Though I checked my Java project sdk, with ctrl+shift+alt+s, it's liberica 17.

The latter error sounds like you have Java 11 in the terminal's path

Thank you for answering. ./mvnw error was actually caused by incorrect JAVA_HOME version. The main topic error was caused by not having maven clear after every run.

@Svetlana please answer your question with the solution that worked for you, so that this question gets an answer.

Answer to my question. The problem was caused by not doing maven clean after application run. As I understand, switching from maven to gradle also helps.
For eliminating ./mvnw problem, check carefully JAVA_HOME environment variable. It may be so, that your project uses SDK 17 but your JAVA_HOME leads to JDK/JRE {another_version}.

I had to run Invalidate Caches in Intellij afterwards as well.
